# Is there a way to skip a conditional statement in a loop after condition has been satisfied?

Tags: c, optimization

Suppose we have a `bool` variable initialized with the value `0`.This variable is to be used in a loop and turn to 1 once a certain condition has been satisfied.
Once it acquire the value of 1 it becomes superfluous so is there a way to skip it in a loop for optimization?

My code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void)
{
    bool var = 0;
    char str[] = "          Hello babz what's up with you?!";
    size_t n, len = strlen(str);
    for (n = 0; n < len; n++) {
        if (str[n] != ' ') {
            var = 1;
        }
        if (var) {
            printf("%c", str[n]);
        }
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Change it into two loops

Comment: break the loop and then create another one for the rest of the execution

Comment: That's brilliant guys,thanks

Comment: This will not compile. And as you already use `bool`, you should use the constant macros, too instead of raw integer constants.

Comment: @layzak: Not that I knew. Your comment is not constructive. If that is some teenage-slang, I did not get it.

Comment: @layzak: Where did I downvote? A comment is not a DV. Although a DV for the question would be well rectified, as you did not even try apparently. This is no consulting service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

drop out of loop once you detect the condition and go to second loop

```
bool var = 0;
char str[] = "          Hello babz what's up with you?!";
size_t n, len = strlen(str);
for (n = 0; n < len; n++) {
    if (str[n] != ' ') {
        var = 1;
        break;
    }
}

  for (; n < len; n++) {
      printf("%c", str[n]);
  }
putchar('\n');
return 0;
```

of course you could get much more idiomatic

```
char *p = str;
while(*p && *p==' ') p++;
puts(p);
```

Answer (score 1):

Code only prints if `str[n] != ' '` is true.  `len` not needed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char str[] = "          Hello babz what's up with you?!";
    size_t n;
    for (n = 0; str[n]; n++) {
        if (str[n] != ' ') {
          fputs(&str[n], stdout);
          break;
        }
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

---

Or use pointers as in [@Jean Jung](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37078852/2410359) and a `puts()` which will append the `'\n'`.

```
int main(void) {
    char str[] = "          Hello babz what's up with you?!";
    char *ptr = str;
    while (*ptr == ' ') ptr++;
    puts(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use pointers:

```
char str[] = "          Hello babz what's up with you?!";
char *pstr = str;
while (*pstr == ' ') pstr++;
while (*pstr != '\0') 
{
    printf("%c", *pstr);
    pstr++;
}
putchar('\n');
```